# Alternate of OR with secondary index : cassandra db

Tags: select, cassandra, lucene, where-clause, cql

I am working with the `SELECT` query where `OR` operation is needed on field, lets say hair-color so query looks like

```
SELECT * from persons where hair-color = 'black' OR hair-color = 'brown';
```

There are only strict operations like `AND` but no `OR` unless hair-color is a primary key and alternatively i can user `IN` like

```
SELECT * from persons where hair-color IN ('black','brown');
```

Now, using Lucene as secondary index, i've built expression for type `phrase` like

```
filter: [ {type: 'phrase', field: 'hair-color', value: 'black'}
```

**Here the main question**,

> how can i do something like

```
filter: [ {type: 'phrase', field: 'hair-color', value: 'black' OR 'brown'}
```

Other way around is to use filter type `contains` like below

```
filter: [ {type: 'contains', field: 'hair-color', values: ['black','brown']}
```

> Extra Information: Working on node js using cassandra node driver

If someone have idea or knowledge regarding this problem, please do help.

Thanks for your time:)